# How to get a numeric derivative function in python?

Tags: python, sympy, derivative

I wonder to know how to get a derivative function in Python to compose a Taylor series.
I know various methods to get a derivative. 
Symbolic using `SymPy` library in the following way:

```
x = sy.Symbol('x')
y = 3*x**2 + 4*x**3
y.diff(x)
```

As a result I get a new function, but I cannot do anything with this function.

The second way is to differentiate using `scipy` library in the following way:

```
def f(x):
    return 3*x**2 + 4*x**3
sc.derivative(f, 2)
```

But it calculates the derivative in some certain point.

But need to get just some another function `f'` which is the derivative of `f`.

Does anybody know to resolve it?

Many thanks.

Comment: y.diff(x).evalf(subs={x: 2.4})

Comment: What do you mean by _numeric derivative_?

Comment: Maybe I am wrong with _numeric derivative_ butmy question was to get a derivative function `g(x)` from the initial function `f(x)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just assign the derivative to a variable and use that variable where you want to use the derivative. Take the Newton-Raphson form of an equation: `f(x) = f(x0) + (x - x0)/f'(x0)`. we need an `f(x)`. Let's call it `fx`:

```
>>> fx = 3*x**2 + 4*x**3
```

We need the derivative. Call it f1x:

```
>>> f1x = fx.diff(x)
```

Assuming `f(x) = 0` we calculate `x` from `x0` as `x = x0 - f(x0)/f'(x0)`. We will call `x` `xnew` and `x0` as `x`:

```
>>> xnew = x - fx/f1x; xnew
x - (4*x**3 + 3*x**2)/(12*x**2 + 6*x)
```

To calculate `xnew` from `x = 1` you use substition (when working with integers) or evaluation with substitution to better preserve accuracy when working with Floats)

```
>>> xnew.subs(x, 1)
>>> xnew.subs(x,1)
11/18
>>> xnew.n(subs={x:1})
0.611111111111111
```

If it makes you feel better to work with the `f(x)` form you can do the same thing as follows (and here I will just show the steps):

```
>>> f = Lambda(x, 3*x**2 + 4*x**3)
>>> f1 = Lambda(x, f(x).diff(x))
>>> xnew = x - f(x)/f1(x); xnew
x - (4*x**3 + 3*x**2)/(12*x**2 + 6*x)
>>> xnew.subs(x, 1)
11/18
```

In either case, be careful to not use `x` as a Python variable for anything other than the SymPy Symbol x. If you do you will lose (temporarily and perhaps mysteriously, if you are new to Python/SymPy) your ability to recreate `f(x)` with an `x`:

```
>>> f(x)
4*x**3 + 3*x**2
>>> x = 2
>>> f(x)  # now interpreted as f(2)
44
```

Oops! Let's get `x` pointing to a Symbol again

```
>>>> from sympy.abc import x
>>> f(x)
4*x**3 + 3*x**2
```

Note: if you want several derivatives to work with at once you can store them in a list and access them by order of derivative:

```
>>> deriv = [f(x).diff(x, i) for i in range(4)]
>>> deriv[2]
6*(4*x + 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use evalf()

```
from sympy import *
x = Symbol('x')
y = 3*x**2 + 4*x**3
t = y.diff(x)
print(t.evalf(subs={x: 2}))
```

**Result:**

**t = y.diff(x)**

```
t = 12 * (x**2) + (6*x)
```

**t.evalf(subs={x: 2})**

```
t(at x =2) : 60
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I need to get just derivative function, not the value of derivative at a specific point.

Comment: g = t.diff(x) <--- 2nd derivative

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear what you are asking. However it seems that the easiest way to clarify the question in this case would be to propose a solution.

Consider

```
from scipy.misc import derivative

def f(x):
    return 3*x**2 + 4*x**3

fprime = lambda x : derivative(f, x, dx=1e-6)
print(fprime(2))
```

Returns

```
60.000000004833964
```

Which is a numeric derivative. You could then repeat the process to get the functions that correspond to higher derivatives and use all this to evaluate your taylor series at as specific point.

Comment: My question was how to get a function `g(x) = f'(x)`? Then cind a derivative `s(x) = g'(x)` so on so far. I need it to compose a Taylor series. I don't need to calculate the value of `f'(x)` at a specific point. I just want to get a function.

Comment: @DavidBijoyan, the function *is* code to get the value at *any* specific point.